# How can I raise a custom exception in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, exception

I have a stored procedure `spMyProc`. The procedure is passed a table name as a parameter `@TableName`. It is important to verify that the table exists before proceeding to the body of the procedure.

How can I create a custom exception to raise an error if the table name is invalid?

I am aware of `TRY` and `CATCH` but I'm unsure how to put this together with custom exceptions.

Regards.

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server? In 2012, we got a new `THROW` keyword....

Comment: Unfortunately 2008! I cant wait to be upgraded to 2014.

Comment: You should be able to achieve what you're looking for with the [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into RAISERROR() funiction.

TRY.. CATCH works pretty same as it would work in any other programming language

```
BEGIN TRY

  -- do your checks 
      IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE NAME = @TableName)
       BEGIN
           RAISERROR('Table does not exist', 16,1)
       END

  -- rest of the code if  checks are passed 
  -- if above checks are not passed and you riase an error 
  -- control will skip any code in TRY Block after the error has been 
  -- Raised and staright jump to Catch block.

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
  -- Do your error logging 
  -- Other stuff 
  -- you have access to ERROR_ functions here to get detailed info about errors
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one of examples supplied here [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) should match your problem. New versions of SQL Server will use [THROW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx) instead of RAISERROR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch and raiseerror for handle the custom exception, for example:

```
begin try   
   --sql statements 
end try
begin catch
    RAISERROR 
    (
    ERROR_MESSAGE(), -- or add your custom message 
    ERROR_SEVERITY(), 
    1,               
    ERROR_NUMBER(),    -- parameter: original error number.
    ERROR_SEVERITY(),  -- parameter: original error severity.
    ERROR_STATE(),     -- parameter: original error state.
    ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-'), -- parameter: original error procedure name.
    ERROR_LINE()       -- parameter: original error line number.
end catch
```